# change multiple boolean text at once

Tags: modifiers, text-object

I have a 3d model that requires a single text stamp in multiple locations. I need to change the text every day for serialization while 3d printing. Right now I am deleting the previous mesh, duplicating a text object, changing the date, converting the text into a mesh and then selecting the new mesh as a target for the boolean modifier. Doing this 15 times a day can get old fast. Is there any way that i can change them all at once?

Comment: Most likely you would need to set up a python script to do this automatically.

Comment: I was really hoping that wasn't the answer. Guess I had better get learning python.